# Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).counterUp is not a function error while trying to retrieve data from select2 select option

Tags: jquery, laravel-blade, jquery-select2

I have a select2 multiple boxes containing data of "package_name" and value of "price" compacted from my Laravel controller, and 2 textboxes for total price and ordered_pacakage, I want to display the prices of any option selected, if its more than 1 option selected, then i need the sum of all the options selected, and i also want to display the package_name of all the option selected in ordered_pacake tectbox, if it's more than 1 it should be seperated with a comma.

i have this code

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <label for="packages"> Packages </label>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-select" name="packages[]" multiple="multiple" id="packagesSelect">
                                        
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <option value="{{ $product->package_price }}">{{ $product->package_name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
                                                                                     </div>
                
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <input type="text" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice" placeholder="0" readonly>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <input type="text" id="ordered_package" name="ordered_package" placeholder="0" readonly>
</div>
```

and a corresponding javascript

```
<script>
    const packagesSelect = document.getElementById("packagesSelect");
    const totalPriceInput = document.getElementById("totalPrice");
    const orderedPackageInput = document.getElementById("ordered_package");

    packagesSelect.addEventListener("change", function () {
        const selectedOptions = Array.from(packagesSelect.selectedOptions);
        const totalPackagePrice = selectedOptions.reduce((sum, option) => sum + parseFloat(option.value), 0);
        totalPriceInput.value = totalPackagePrice.toFixed(2);

        const selectedPackageNames = selectedOptions.map(option => option.text);
        orderedPackageInput.value = selectedPackageNames.join(", ");
    });
</script>
```

I am getting:

> "Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).counterUp is not a function"

in my console on the load of the page, and if I select any option, nothing happens

Comment: None of your code that you are showing us even mentions jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [jQuery CountUp plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js)

how to use:

```
$('.counter').counterUp();
```

Or with extra parameters:

```
$('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000
});
```

Comment: thanks, i have 2 versions of Jquery linked to my page.